# What does "jumping anyone on a depth chart" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

> Except that now Lynch is done. At least in Denver. There may be other teams out there who want to give him a shot, but it’s hard to see him **jumping anyone on a depth chart** — assuming he’s claimed.

I don't understand the phrase in bold above. I looked up 'jump'. The closest I can get is '**to attack**', but I don't feel it can fit for this context.

What does "**jumping anyone on a depth chart**" mean?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/john-elway-admits-mistake-cuts-former-first-round-qb-paxton-lynch-180325107.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret it to mean *surpass*. *Jump* is commonly used to describe some kind of rise or increase:

> [jump](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jump)
>   b. To rise suddenly in position or rank: jumped over two others with more seniority.
>   (TFD)

Wikipedia gives

> In sports, a [depth chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_chart) is used to show the placements of the starting players and the secondary players. Generally a starting player will be listed first or on top while a back-up will be listed below. Depth charts also tend to resemble the actual position locations of certain players.

The article is saying that Lynch is unlikely to **surpass** anyone on a depth chart. I believe it's implying that he would not be able to get a starting role. He would be back-up player.

Comment: Is this usage of jump easily understood by native speakers? I feel it's hard to get that idea. Maybe, it's a lot easier for me if it put something like: *jump over anyone* ...

Comment: Yes, I believe it should be easily understood by native speakers. _However_, I did find it a little odd. I would expect _jumping over_ or possibly _leapfrogging_, but that's just _my_ opinion. I believe it's certainly understandable. It's probably hard for you to get because it is a figurative usage of _jump_. And there are many different usages. That's why I liked "leapfrog" or "jump over". Imagine three men standing in a line: A, B, and C. Then B jumps over A. Now, the line becomes B, A, C. This is the kind of rearrangement of the order of the players that's implied.